# Accessing pushViewController's methods from popViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I am working on a view based application. In this i have two viewcontrollers. They are: Rootviewcontroller and Detailviewcontroller.

Now i am passing a values to Detailviewcontroller using pushViewController method.It works fine. But now when i pop out from this Detailviewcontroller i should access myfunction in Rootviewcontroller. Is it possible please suggest?

Any help would be apprecited !

-Sathiya

Answer (score 4):

call myfunction in the root view controller's viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method or the viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method, depending on when you want it to be called.  that way whenever that controller appears the code you need will be run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question 100%, but I think you want to access the methods of the Root ViewController from another View Controller further up the stack?

You can do something like this in DetailViewController:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController*)self.navigationController.topViewController;
```

Now that you have a reference to the Root, you can call methods on it as you wish.

Comment: Yes i want to access the methods of the Rootviewcontroller from another view Controller. As per your suggestion i tried and the rootviewcontroller methods but the application gets terminated. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Store instance of rootViewController in AppDelegate.

```
// AppDelegate.h
RootViewController* rootViewController;
```

Add an access method to the implementation.

```
// AppDelegate.m     
- (UIViewController*) GetRootViewController {
    return rootViewController;
}
```

Call this method to get the rootViewController from anywhere in your app.

```
UIViewController* controller =
    [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] GetRootViewController];
```